# Как сделать 301 редирект с 404 на главную (nginx)

Tags: nginx, redirect, php-nginx, error404

Всем доброго времени суток! Имеется сервер в связке nginx+phpfpm. Никак не получается правильно настроить редирект с 404 на главную. Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Не очень понятно что такое 301 редирект с 404 если и то и другое коды ответов. Конфиг nginx в студию

Answer (score 0):

Без конфига `nginx` или хотя бы какая используется `CMS` сложно точно подсказать.
Вам нужно в секции `server` прописать нужные страницы ошибок и указать к ним страницу для вывода.

```
server {
...
error_page  403 404 /index.php;
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

В файл `.htaccess` добавьте:

`ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yoursite.com/404.php`

**В Вашем случае:**

`ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yoursite.com/index.php`

**Для nginx**

`#nginx configuration`

`error_page 404 http://www.yoursite.com/404.php`

Разместите это в секции server {} конфигурационного файла nginx

Comment: На сколько мне известно, .htaccess - это для апача, а мне нужны директивы для nginx.

Comment: Советую тогда воспользоваться сервисом: https://winginx.com/ru/htaccess , ответ дополнил, это следует разместить в секции server {} конфигурационного файла nginx